# When I send a letter to the mail gives an error 'tuple' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: html, django

I do so that after registration to the post office a letter is sent but it gives me an error

The letter arrives in the mail, but gives an error and should redirect to another url 'tuple' object has no attribute 'get'

my Traceback:

File "D:\Users\MAestro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "D:\Users\MAestro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\deprecation.py" in **call**
  96.             response = self.process_response(request, response)

File "D:\Users\MAestro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\middleware\clickjacking.py" in process_response
  26.         if response.get('X-Frame-Options') is not None:

Exception Type: AttributeError at /register/
Exception Value: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'get'

Settings

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.mail.ru'
EMAIL_PORT = 2525
EMAIL_HOST_USER = "itraptor@mail.ru"
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = "labrador75"
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True

SERVER_EMAIL = EMAIL_HOST_USER
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = EMAIL_HOST_USER
```

views.py

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegisterForm(request.POST)

        username = request.POST['username']
        password1 = request.POST['password1']
        password2 = request.POST['password2']
        email = request.POST['email']

        context = {'form': form,
                   'username': username,
                   'password1': password1,
                   'password2': password2,
                   'email': email}

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()

            return redirect('/loginNow/') , send_mail('Тема', 'Тело письма', settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER, [email])

    else:
        form = RegisterForm()
        context = {'form': form
                   }

    return render(request, 'registration/registred.html', context)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are returning a tuple here

```
return redirect('/loginNow/') , send_mail('Тема', 'Тело письма', settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER, [email])
```

two comma separated values in form of `a, b` means tuple in python which is a data structure. You should do

```
if form.is_valid():
    form.save()
    send_mail('Тема', 'Тело письма', settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER, [email])
    return redirect('/loginNow/')
```